# How do I Add Contacts to Group from an Activity Report?

Tags: activities, civireport, groups

There is a choice in Activity Reports to Add Contacts to Group, on the  top right - so I created a new Group and chose that Group, but there is not a button to click to complete the add. It's not automatic. I'm on Civi 4.6.3.

Comment: I tried to duplicate on the demo site - Drupal and Civi 4.6.4 - and could not - the demo site does open an additional pop-up window to confirm the groups add that I don't see in 4.6.3, see http://d46.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/report/instance/3 . I'm using the Google Chromium browser on Ubuntu, got the same result with the Chrome browser on Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

click on the Preview Report button and you will get the 'Add contacts to group' action. Just tested it on the demo site running CiviCRM 4.6.4 using Safari and Chrome browsers http://d46.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/report/instance/3

Comment: Hey Kennedy, thanks but does not make any difference - action does not appear. I'll check for any blockers in my browser, clear my cache, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You should start by upgrading to the latest version (4.6.5).  Most probably it was a bug that was fixed for 4.6.4. (You can confirm this before upgrading by looking at at the [bugs fixed in 4.6.4](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/issues/?jql=project%20%3D%20CRM%20AND%20resolution%20%3D%20%22Fixed%2FCompleted%22%20AND%20fixVersion%20%3D%204.6.4)).